# Draw polyline on map in javascript api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to draw polyline on map, but line is not adding to the map,please help me determine where I am making a mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

   </style>
   <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/"></script>
   <script>
     var map,toolbar;

     require(["esri/map",
            "esri/toolbars/draw",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", 
            "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
            "esri/graphic",
            "esri/Color",
            "dojo/on",              
            "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map,Draw,SimpleMarkerSymbol,SimpleLineSymbol,Graphic,Color,on) {
       map = new Map("map", {
         basemap: "streets",  
         center: [-122.45, 37.75], 
         zoom: 13
       });
       map.on("load",initToolbar);


       var sls = new SimpleLineSymbol(
       SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASH,
       new Color([255,0,0]),3);
       //var mybutton = dojo.byId("drawPoly");
       dojo.connect(drawPoly,"onclick",drawPolyLine);

       function drawPolyLine(){

         toolbar = new Draw(map, { showTooltips: true });
         toolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POLYLINE);

       }

       function initToolbar(map) {

          toolbar = new Draw(map);
          toolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);

       }

       function addToMap(evt) {
          alert("Index");
          toolbar.deactivate();
          var symbol = sls;

          var graphic = new Graphic(evt.geometry, symbol);
          map.graphics.add(graphic);
       }

     });
 </script>  
</head>
   <body>
     <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="drawPoly">Draw Polyline</button> 
       <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function `function initToolbar(map){ //rest of code... }` 
remove the parms map , because it create a confilct between the global variable map and the passed param to the function .

It become : `function initToolbar(){ //rest of code... }`

Answer (score 1):

There were just a few minor errors.  Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

   </style>
   <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.15/"></script>
   <script>
     var map,toolbar;

     require(["esri/map",
            "esri/toolbars/draw",
            "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
            "esri/graphic",
            "esri/Color",
            "dojo/on",
            "dojo/dom",
            "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map,Draw,SimpleLineSymbol,Graphic,Color,on, dom) {
       map = new Map("map", {
         basemap: "streets",  
         center: [-122.45, 37.75], 
         zoom: 13
       });

       var sls = new SimpleLineSymbol(
       SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASH,
       new Color([255,0,0]),3);
       var mybutton = dojo.byId("drawPoly");
       on(mybutton,"click",initToolbar);


       function initToolbar() {
          toolbar = new Draw(map, { showTooltips: true });
          toolbar.activate(Draw.POLYLINE);
          toolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);

       }

       function addToMap(evt) {
          alert("Index");
          toolbar.deactivate();
          var symbol = sls;

          var graphic = new Graphic(evt.geometry, symbol);
          map.graphics.add(graphic);
       }

     });
 </script>  
</head>
   <body>
     <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="drawPoly">Draw Polyline</button> 
       <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: fixing the OPs code is substantially less valuable than teaching them what they are doing wrong.